# Route [/download] not defined. (View:

Tags: laravel, eloquent, laravel-5.8

hi I am downloading data directly from URL, but when I try to make a button that when I click on it then it becomes downloadable then it said:
Route [/download] not defined.

> D:\xampp\htdocs\laravel\webpro5\resources\views\showrecord.blade.php

code of button:

```
  <div align="center">
      <a href="{{ route('/download') }}" class="btn btn-success">Export to Excel</a>
    </div>
```

route:

```
  Route::get('/download', function(){
    return Excel::download(new ExcelsExport, 'importpdfs.xlsx');
  });
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The `route()` function expects a single parameter that matches a **named** route. Currently, you don't have a named one. Either use the `url()` function:

```
<a href="{{ url("/download") }}">...</a>
```

or name your route:

```
Route::get("/download", ...)->name("download");
```

Answer (score 0):

```
<div align="center">
  <a href="/download" class="btn btn-success">Export to Excel</a>
</div>
```

or

```
<div align="center">
      <a href="{{ url("/download") }}" class="btn btn-success">Export to Excel</a>
</div>
```

route helper is used for named routes.

Additionally you can do

```
Route::get('/download', 'Controller@Method')->name('download');
```

then you can use the route helper like this:

```
{{ route('download') }}
```